# JavaScript in an iframe on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockout.js

I have a problem to run JavaScript in an iframe on IE (need to work on IE9,  quirks mode).

It comes that

`["click", "mousemove", "keypress"].forEach(function(name){}`

throws an error

> Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

also Knockout.js is not working

> 'ko' is undefined

Code is based on Rainloop webmail app. Header for it (iframe) looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js rl-booted-trigger rl-started-trigger">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta id="rl-head-viewport" name="viewport" content="width=950,maximum-scale=2">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <script type="text/javascript"> if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}}; </script>
    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=./?/NoScript" />
    </noscript>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=./?/BadBrowser" /> 
    <![endif]-->
    <script data-cfasync="false">
        if (!window.navigator || !window.navigator.cookieEnabled) {
            window.document.location.replace('./?/NoCookie');
        }
    </script>
    <meta name="Author" content="RainLoop Team" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noodp" />
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
[... rest is from the Rianloop JS code...]
```

Any clue how to get that to work?

Comment: Which version of IE? Check also, that you're running the page in standards mode.

Comment: Browser compatibility on MDN shows  `forEach` works only for IE 9 and above

Comment: I had a similar issue recently. Can you show the head of the document in question?

Comment: @tenor528 parent or iframe content?

Comment: @JackTheKnife  I'm guessing the iFrame, since that's where the errors are being thrown.

Comment: @tenor528 OP updated with more info. Thanks!

Comment: Not possible, `forEach` is not implemented in Quirks mode (it's IE5.5!). As Matt said, "IE 9 and above", and in standards mode only.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be related. Issues before seemed to be stemming from JS code above the `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Comment: @Teemu Good point. Switched to standards mode and got it to work. You can post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Teemu suggestion solution was to change parent window mode from Quirks to Standards as `forEach` is not implemented in Quirks as well Konckout.js is not working in that mode.